# Is there any way to extract keywords and keyterms of an academic field?

Tags: publications, keywords

I'm trying to do a personal research project on a field, e.g. "quantum physics" and wanted to analyse which keywords are the most important or have the most papers in a field. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you have the text files, then excel has the find() function that will find words or phrases... But other programs will be better.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm talking about a field in general. Like what are the most important keywords (or the most frequent) in the last five years in quantom physics for example.

Comment: For which publication/service provider? These stats can change greatly depending on where you are looking and who your intended audience is. I think as stated this is too broad of a question and  you need to define the problem a bit better.

Comment: @scrappedcola I'm trying to expand a dataset of academic texts that I currently have, but the domain is niche and only using available keywords in documents does not help me find significant number of similar papers (I have tried the scopus API before). I was thinking of finding better keywords in order to have better query's in scopus database.

Comment: Go find a research librarian at your university library (preferably the physics library). Politely ask them. Done.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks, but our librarians are not as updated as you'd think they are.

Comment: @FarhoodET - you might just have to dig a bit. Not the librarian at the front desk. Ask for a research librarian. They are expert at how to extract what you want from the databases. Take several relevant articles to show what you would like to find, and take several that look like they might be relevant but aren't.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the last 5 years a good chance would be

- a current textbook/PhD thesis (many are published on university servers and open access) on that field that has a glossary
- browsing/downloading the most cited papers on journal websites (there are often tags, keywords for every paper added by the authors) and noting them down
- doing text analytics/statistics on your own with such tools after [converting PDF to text](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4759):

  - Matlab [Text Analytics Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/text-analytics.html)
  - https://github.com/HamidMosalla/WordFrequencyCounter
  - http://www.writewords.org.uk/word_count.asp
  - http://neon.niederlandistik.fu-berlin.de/textstat/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out the free software tool VOSviewer http://www.vosviewer.com/:

> VOSviewer is a software tool for constructing and visualizing bibliometric networks. These networks may for instance include journals, researchers, or individual publications, and they can be constructed based on citation, bibliographic coupling, co-citation, or co-authorship relations. VOSviewer also offers text mining functionality that can be used to construct and visualize co-occurrence networks of important terms extracted from a body of scientific literature.